# Simple JavaScript template literals to insert iterated values (e.g. array elements) into HTML

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, templates, template-literals

I want to use a template literal, i.e. backticks, to insert elements from an array into my HTML. Essentially, I want to create my own extremely simple templating system.

I expected `forEach` to work, with each iterated callback just inserting the returned text. However, it just returns `undefined`, e.g.:

```js
const myArray = ['square', 'triangle', 'circle'];
document.querySelector('div').innerHTML = `
  <p>Some shapes:<\p>
  <ul>
    ${myArray.forEach(elmt => `
      <li>${elmt}</li>
    `)}
  </ul>
`;
```

```html
<div></div>
```

So, how do I do this?

Answer (score 6):

**Use `myArray.map(...).join('')` instead of `myArray.forEach(...)`.**

In a template literal, the results of code within a placeholder, i.e. within `${...}`, are coerced to a string before insertion. A `forEach(...)` loop only returns [`undefined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Return_value) by definition. In contrast, `map(...)` returns a use-able value, i.e. an [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Return_value). However, when the array is co-erced to a string, by default commas are inserted between elements. This results in unwanted text nodes, each containing a comma, appearing between the intended insertions. However, this default can be changed by explicitly joining the array elements with an empty string using `.join('')`:

```js
const myArray = ['square', 'triangle', 'circle'];
document.querySelector('div').innerHTML = `
  <p>Some shapes:<\p>
  <ul>
    ${myArray.map(elmt => `
      <li>${elmt}</li>
    `).join('')}
  </ul>
`;
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Note that this strategy can easily be used with other iterables by first simply coercing them to an array, e.g. by using `[...mySet].map...` instead of `myArray.map...`, etc.